# Ошибка в мобильных браузерах при использовании input file multiple

Tags: javascript, mobile, браузер

Пример описанный ниже не работает в некоторых мобильных браузерах ( например: android 6.0.1 Chrome 58.0.3029.83 )

HTML:

```
<form action="" id="iForm">
  <input type="file" multiple name="files" id="iFiles" accept="image/*" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
$('#iForm').on('change', 'input#iFiles', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Спустя 5-10сек после выбора файлов ( картинок в моем случаи ) выбивает ошибку браузера "Опаньки..." или перезагружает страницу или происходит полное зависание браузера.

**Как это можно исправить?**

Если увеличить JS код до:

```
$('#iForm').on('change', 'input#iFiles', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var files = this.files;
  for (var key in files)
  {
    if (parseInt(key) >= 0)
    {
      console.log(files[key]);
      console.log({
        fileName : files[key].name,
        fileType : files[key].type,
        fileSize : files[key].size
      });
    }
  }
  return false;
});
```

Можно заметить через Remote Devices, что первый console.log в цикле возвращает пустой объект, но второй console.log возвращает имя, тип и размер текущего файла ( размер в случаи с android 6.0.1 Chrome 58.0.3029.83 равен 0 байт )